# изменение Google формы встроенной в web страницу

Tags: javascript

Есть Google форма встроенная  в страницу с помощью фрейма

`<iframe src="https://docs.google.com/forms/d/e/1FAIpQLSdCITXj-1d1brBB1fx__CdaWfPCOXq9nRC_PWOurlZOQ60h1g/viewform?embedded=true" width="640" height="947" frameborder="0" marginheight="0" marginwidth="0">Загрузка…</iframe>`

Во фрейме имеется input

`<input type="text" class="quantumWizTextinputPaperinputInput exportInput" jsname="YPqjbf" autocomplete="off" tabindex="0" 
aria-label="Имя" aria-describedby="i.desc.1633920210 i.err.1633920210" name="entry.2005620554" value="" required="" dir="auto" data-initial-dir="auto" data-initial-value="" aria-invalid="true">`

Пожалуйста подскажите , как c помощью javascript внести в input  value="123" и type="hidden"

Comment: Внешнее окно не имеет доступа к `iframe`, когда в `iframe` и в главном окне разные домены.

Comment: У меня имеется аналогичная ситуация с Google документом. нашел решение как его встроенный фрейм править https://web-analytics.me/custom_fields_in_google_forms. Возможно ли как там?